# Unable to deposit ether from External Account to Contract

Tags: truffle, testing

This is my first question on StackOverflow.

I am having trouble sending Ether from an account to the contract. The DApp I am creating is separated into a Data & App contract, where the Data contract is supposed to function as a database.

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

 import "./FlightSuretyData.sol";
 import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";


address private contractOwner;          // Account used to deploy contract

uint constant AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE = 10 ether;

address payable public dataAddress;
FlightSuretyData data;

/**
* @dev Contract constructor
*
*/
constructor (address payable _data, address payable _firstAirline) payable public
{
    contractOwner = msg.sender;
    dataAddress = _data;
    data = FlightSuretyData(_data);

    data.registerAirline("Default", _firstAirline);

}

************************* PROBLEM AREA **********************************
*************************************************************************

/**
* @dev Deposit money to the smart contract
*
*/
function deposit(uint amount) public payable {
   require(msg.value == amount, "Amount not the same!");
   // nothing else to do!

 }

function fund() public payable {

  // make sure enough ether
  require (msg.value >= AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE, "Not enough ether to deposit");

  // transfer money from caller of function to THIS contract
  // PROBLEM
  deposit(msg.value);

  // transfer money from THIS contract to DATA contract
  require(address(this).balance >= AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE, "do not have enough to pay");

  dataAddress.transfer(msg.value);

  require(dataAddress.balance >= AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE, "data contract did not get ether");

  data.fund();
}

  *************************************************************************
```

I have intentionally given minimal code so that the reader doesn't get sucked into the project details. Also after much debugging, I have figured out the problem is with the **deposit function**. It simply doesn't deposit (I checked this with the require statement right after).

Indeed, when I run the test below, I get `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` :

```
    await config.flightSuretyApp.fund({from: accounts[3], value: 
    web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether")});
```

Let me know if more code is needed!

`function() external payable { fund(); }`

flightSuretyData.fund() is: `function fund () public { require (airlineDB[tx.origin].isRegistered, "Can only fund registered airlines"); airlineDB[msg.sender].isFunded = true; isAirline[msg.sender] = true; }`

Comment: What's `REGISTRATION_FEE`? I don't see it defined in the code... is it possible it's more than `AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE`? If you just have `deposit(msg.value)` and then `require(address(this).balance >= msg.value);`, does that work? If so, work your way back up to find out which line is causing the problem. My guess would be either `dataAddress.transfer()` (perhaps if that address is a contract) or `data.fund()`.

Comment: Or a difference between `REGISTRATION_FEE` and `AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE`, but I'm guessing that's just an error introduced in copy/pasting your code.

Comment: So uncommenting everything except `deposit(msg.value)` and       `require(address(this).balance >= REGISTRATION_FEE, "do not have enough to pay");` makes the test pass!!! Thank you! I have tried `data.fund()` separately and that works, so I guess the issue is with `dataAddress.transfer()`, since that address **indeed is a contract.** Is there a special way to transfer ether from this contract to that one?

Comment: Does the contract at `dataAddress` have a payable fallback function? If not, it will refuse to accept ether transfers. If it _does_, then make sure the code in that function (if any) is not reverting and that it can succeed with only 2300 gas.

Comment: Updated post. Not sure if it uses more than 2300 gas. What do I do? Could I add the gas as a parameter?

Comment: That definitely uses more than 2300 gas, which is all you get in a `.transfer()`. Just mark the `FlightSuretyData.fund()` function `payable` and replace `data.transfer(msg.value); data.fund()` with `data.fund.value(msg.value)()`.

Comment: Amazing! It worked! You saved me after 2 days of struggle! In general, the code above works for an arbitrary large gas usage function, correct?

Comment: Yes. `.transfer()` is a special case that only forwards a certain amount of gas. Normal function calls forward all available gas.

Comment: Please add your reply as an answer so I can put it as the "recommended" one :)